# csv export not working with symfony 3

Tags: symfony, download, export-to-csv

I try to do a csv export on my symfony project and i think that something is wrong because nothing happens and i have no error...??

```
public function exportCsv($customers)
{
$fileName = "export_" . date("d_m_Y") . ".csv";
$response = new StreamedResponse();


$response->setCallback(function() use ($customers){
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

    // Nom des colonnes du CSV
    fputcsv($handle, array('Name',
        'Adress',
        'City',
        'Code'
    ), ';');

    //Champs
    foreach ($customers as $index => $customer)
    {
        //dump($client);die();
        fputcsv($handle,array(
            $customer->getName(),
            $customer->getAdress(),
            $customer->getCity(),
            $customer->getCode(),
        ),';');
    }
    fclose($handle);
});


$response->setStatusCode(200);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8', 'application/force-download');
$response->headers->set('Content-Disposition','attachment; filename='.$fileName);


return $response;

}
```

I call this function in my controler like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['export']))
{
    $export = $exp->exportCsv($customers);

}
```

Have you any idea, please???

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what happened in your streamed response and what is the error, you just have to call the callback function outside the response.

```
$callback = function() use ($customers){
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w+');

    // Nom des colonnes du CSV
    fputcsv($handle, array('Name',
        'Adress',
        'City',
        'Code'
    ), ';');

    //Champs
    foreach ($customers as $index => $customer)
    {
        //dump($client);die();
        fputcsv($handle,array(
            $customer->getName(),
            $customer->getAdress(),
            $customer->getCity(),
            $customer->getCode(),
        ),';');
    }
    fclose($handle);
};

$callback();exit;
```

And after just delete the last line and insert the callback function inside the StreamedResponse object `$response->setCallback($callback);`

Comment: ok!! thank your your answer! i did it and i saw the StreamedResponse content. For this it's ok but i dont know why the csv file not downloading...?

Comment: If you see the content you don&#39;t have any error. May be you don't have a return inside your action. You have to return your variable `export` but normally if you don&#39;t return anything Symfony throw an error saying that you have to return a response.